# Laravel/PHPUnit: Class not being mocked when tests are run

Tags: laravel, mocking, lumen, phpunit

I'm testing a class that calls a custom service and want to mock out the custom service.

The error is:

```
App\Jobs\CustomApiTest::getrandomInfo
Error: Call to a member function toArray() on null
```

This is because in `getrandomInfo()` there is a database call to fetch an ID and the test database is currently returning null because there is no entry, but the test should never even go that far because I am mocking out the `getData` function.

Machine Config:

Laravel 5.2

PHPUnit 4.8

I can not update my configuration.

**MainClass.php**

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\Services\CustomApi;

class MainClass
{
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $date = Carbon::yesterday();
            $data = (new CustomApi($date))->getData();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error("Error, {$e->getMessage()}");
        }
    }
}
```

**MainClassTest.php**

```
nameSpace App\Jobs;
use App\Services\CustomApi;
class MainClassTest extends \TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function handleGetsData()
    {
    $data = json_encode([
            'randomInfo' => '',
            'moreInfo' => ''
        ]);
    $customApiMock = $this->getMockBuilder(App\Services\CustomApi::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['getData'])
            ->getMock('CustomApi', ['getData']);
        $customApiMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getData')
            ->will($this->returnValue($data));

        $this->app->instance(App\Services\CustomApi::class, $customApiMock);

    (new MainClass())->handle();
    }
}
```

**CustomApi Snippet**

```
namespace App\Services;
class CustomApi
{
    /**
     * @var Carbon
     */
    private $date;

    public function __construct(Carbon $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    public function getData() : string
    {
        return json_encode([
            'randomInfo' => $this->getrandomInfo(),
            'moreInfo' => $this->getmoreInfo()
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have tried many variations of the above code including:

```
Not using `disableOriginalConstructor()` when creating $externalApiMock.
Not providing parameters to `getMock()` when creating $externalApiMock.
Using `bind(App\Services\CustomApi::class, $customApiMock)` instead of instance(App\Services\CustomApi::class, $customApiMock) for the app.
Using willReturn($data)`` instead `will($this->returnValue($data))`.
```

Comment: Could you please update to latest Laravel? And post your errors?

Comment: @Bart, I cannot update to latest Laravel because the update requires many adjustments to the code base and needs to be done in sections but development still needs to move forward.
I have updated the question with the error I receive.

Comment: I still suggest updating, if you are unable, then there is probably something wrong with your code, or your IDE is not capable of changing the required things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Service Provider and registering it in the app.php file. It seemed like the application was not saving the instance in the containers but works when it is bound to the service.